# How to make Silex\Debug return JSON inside Silex App

Tags: php, json, symfony, silex

I have a class that throws errors that extends from the base Exception.

The App's core is Silex Micro-Framework - but due to the fact that I am more fluent in Laravel than Symfony (despite Laravel being derived from it) I tend to use some packages from illuminate (hence the reason why you will see some `use Illuminate\`)

I want to throw an exception when an error occurs but I am getting the integrated Whoops instead. I would like to return JSON instead. (its not the full stack whoops but Symfony\component\debug instead)

Ideally `array('status' => <code>, 'message_content');`

Question is: a) how do i do it considering its silex with debug that looks like whoops (this service is on by default). b) is there a way to use my class that extends Exception bellow or am i in need of creating an entire new Exception class that suits my needs instead from scratch

```
namespace Api\Manager\Validation;

use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;

class ValidationException extends \Exception {

/**
 * @var MessageBag
 */
protected $errors;

/**
 * @param string     $message
 * @param MessageBag $errors
 */
function __construct($message, MessageBag $errors)
{
    $this->errors = $errors;

    parent::__construct($message);
}

/**
 * Get form validation errors
 *
 * @return MessageBag
 */
public function getErrors()
{
    return $this->errors;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the WhoopsServiceProvider to integrate into Silex - you should have the following in your app.php or index_dev.php.

```
$app->register(new WhoopsServiceProvider());
```

You can see the code for this [here](https://github.com/filp/whoops/blob/master/src/Whoops/Provider/Silex/WhoopsServiceProvider.php).

It appears to hardcode the PrettyPageHandler.

```
$app['whoops.error_page_handler'] = $app->share(function() {
    return new PrettyPageHandler;
});
```

If you fork this provider/copy it into your own, then you should be able to replace this with the JsonRespondeHandler.

You will also need to remove some of the other code in the Provider. e.g. the whoops.silex_info_handler will not work for you as it includes some calls like addDataTable() which I think are specific to the PrettyPageHandler class.

```
$app['whoops'] = $app->share(function() use($app) {
    $run = new Run;
    $run->allowQuit(false);
    $run->pushHandler($app['whoops.error_page_handler']);
    $run->pushHandler($app['whoops.silex_info_handler']);
    return $run;
});
```

Without actually testing the above I believe that should mean all your exceptions caught by Whoops will be rendered in JSON, so you won't (and shouldn't) need to create individual exception classes that render JSON specifically.

**Update**

It's actually a lot more straightforward than that. Just put the below in your index_dev.php after "$app = new Silex\Application();".

```
$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) use($app) {
    return $app->json(array("error" => $e->getMessage()),$code);
});
```

Then exceptions will be output as JSON. The solution is actually from another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872816/capture-exceptions-with-a-different-handler-for-applications-rest).

Comment: I edited the original question - I found out that it wasn't Whoops (despite looking exactly like whoops) it is in fact symfony's default debug mode which invokes Symfony\component\debug by default

Comment: See my update - let me know if it answers your updated question or if you are still having issues.

Comment: it works - however im disappointed that it must be at the same level as APP that I must do this - too bad it cant be controller dependent and I can just selectively extend it as a base class.

Comment: You can still do this - have a read of the Silex docs:
http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#error-handlers
You can restrict the Exceptions that you will catch in this way.
You could probably even call $app->error() from within a controller but this might lead to unexpected behavior where you make two calls and one overrides the other (not sure exactly how this would work, you would need to investigate the Silex\Application error() method.